# How to make HTTP requests in actionscript 2

Tags: http, actionscript-2

I'm fairly new to actionscript 2 and HTTP, but I need to be able to send an HTTP request message through actionscript 2. I'm not to sure how to do this. Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the LoadVars class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html#305040

In particular you'll be using the sendAndLoad method.

Comment: Oh - the only tricky bit is that you need two LoadVars objects to do this - one to send the data and one to get the result that's sent back from the server. You add properties to the sending LoadVars object (this is the data you want to send) and then give it a reference to the recieving LoadVars objects when you call sendAndLoad. The docs on sendAndLoad give a good example:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001174.html